# How Do I Run an .exe From My Program and Obtain a Handle

Tags: c++, winapi

How do I open a process and obtain a handle too it in C++. I know that there is `system()` and numerous methods to obtain a handle, but I'm sure there is a neater/alternative way to doing this. Or is `system()` the only way to open a .exe from inside your own?

Comment: What kind of handle do you think you need? Process? Window? Thread? File?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A common way to do this is to use the Win32 API [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The last parameter of this function is an out parameter to a structure ([`PROCESS_INFORMATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) containing the handle to the process (`HANDLE hProcess`).

Comment: I must have skimmed over that half a dozen times while searching MSDN. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: That does not give you a handle to the process.